# Minecraft launcher is odd at 15.10?

Tags: launcher, freeze, minecraft

When I open Minecraft, the launcher opens and freezes at the `"Starting Launcher..."` part sometimes. I need to log out and in to resolve the issue. If there's a solution could you please enlighten me? I don't want to have to log in and out so many times.

Answer (score 0):

I get occasional freezes in Minecraft and use `sudo killall java` in the terminal. This ends all java processes, which for me is only Minecraft and the launcher. No need to logout and in again.

Comment: I'll try that thank you user1326419 :>